# React-Native: rendering dynamic content?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to render dynamic content in RN?
for example, I have

```
var content = '<View><Text>ABC</Text></View>';
```

Can I reference this variable and render the content expressed by that string?

The initiative: I want to implement a textfield that user could type text and/or emoji (with react-native-emoji support) inside. If the above is doable it could be done easily.

Comment: how about creating a component or helper function for that?

Comment: Currently the only way I can think of is to create that helper function to parse the string and return the control. Since I believe it might be a common need so I am wondering whether there is some component already supporting that?

Comment: you can use map function in array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446029/render-content-dynamically-from-an-array-map-function-in-react-native.