# Render Content Dynamically from an array map function in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm trying to get data from an array and using map function to render content. Look at

```
**{this.lapsList()}**
```

and the associated

```
**lapsList()**
```

function to understand what I'm trying to do. The result is nothing is displaying (Views under view, etc.) Here is my simplified code:

```
class StopWatch extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    laps: []
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <View><Text>coucou test</Text></View>
          {this.lapsList()}
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}

lapsList() {

    this.state.laps.map((data) => {
      return (
        <View><Text>{data.time}</Text></View>
      )
    })

}

_handlePressLap() {

  console.log("press lap");

  if (!this.state.isRunning) {

    this.setState({
      laps: []
    })

    return

  }

  let laps = this.state.laps.concat([{'time': this.state.timeElapsed}]);

  this.setState({
      laps: laps
  })

  console.log(laps);

}
```

}

Comment: please also describe your problem

Comment: Done. In fact nothing is displaying (generated views).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Don't forget to `return` the mapped array , like:

```
lapsList() {

    return this.state.laps.map((data) => {
      return (
        <View><Text>{data.time}</Text></View>
      )
    })

}
```

Reference for the `map()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I want to get index of the item too, but unable to get that.
`this.state.array.map((item, index) =>`.
The index, I am getting from that is some object *with Cyclic reference*, so unable to print it as well. Any way to get index value for that?

Answer (score 10):

Try moving the `lapsList` function out of your class and into your render function:

```
render() {
  const lapsList = this.state.laps.map((data) => {
    return (
      <View><Text>{data.time}</Text></View>
    )
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <View><Text>coucou test</Text></View>
        {lapsList}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks Nader, but could you tell me why it's better please?

Comment: Hey, wouldn't say it's better, just another way of structuring your code I guess. Either way will work as long as you return your component in map.

Comment: Ok, I asked that because sometimes it takes less ressources! ;-) Btw thanks for your code!

Answer (score 2):

```
lapsList() {

    return this.state.laps.map((data) => {
      return (
        <View><Text>{data.time}</Text></View>
      )
    })
}
```

You forgot to return the map. this code will resolve the issue.