# iteratively change properties and states of components

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to port a HTML5 app over to React Native. In my original app I had 24 DOM elements, each with a custom length, maxLength, description, isActive and color attribute. I would use jQuery.each(); to iterate over the elements and use a constructor function to store the index and jQuery object for each element.

The constructor had various prototype functions to get/set the attributes along with associated style changes. Some functions would change neighboring elements' attributes and styles, and I would access these functions using the array of constructed objects.

So my question. How can I follow a similar pattern in React Native? Specifically, how do I add 'elements' into an array and then iterate through that array making visual/data changes to selected elements?

An example:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var activities = [];
    Activity = function (idx, ele) {
        this.idx = idx;
        this.ele = ele;
    }
    $('.activity').each(function(index){
        activities[index] = new Activity(index, $(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: Pretty broad. Some code samples would help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the properties in an array and then iterate through it. To change them manipulate the array. Maybe put it into the state.

```
const elements = [
  {
    style: {
      color: 'red',
    },
    text: 'first',
  },
  {
    style: {
      color: 'green',
    },
    text: 'second',
  },
  {
    style: {
      color: 'blue',
    },
    text: 'third',
  },
]
```

…

```
elements.map((element) =>
  <View style={element.style}>
    <Text>{element.text}</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: For an app with a defined number of elements, is the map function really necessary? I can see this answer is in a similar vien:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446029/render-content-dynamically-from-an-array-map-function-in-react-native

Comment: Well you wanted to iterate through the array, what's bad about map? The elements should update only when you make changes to their data, not on each map call.

Comment: It's good. I think I understand how it works now. The jsx in the map function only changes if the values do. So where does the map have to be to update what is rendered? I'm changing my environment to allow terminal logs so I can test.

Comment: Feel free to put it directly to your render function :)