# Expo TypeError this.state.txt.map in not an object

Tags: arrays, react-native, expo

I'm trying to display an array on my project and I've run into an error.

Here is all my code regarding this issue.

```
  state = {
    isModalVisible: false,
    txt: ["Hello", "My", "Friend"],
    tuxt: ["Whats","up","Bussy"],
    key: [0,1,2]

  };

renderFeed = () =>{
    return this.state.txt.map((card) => {
      return (
          <Text>{card}</Text>
        )
    })
  }

<View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginTop: 5}}>
{this.renderFeed()}
</View>
```

I'm not entirely sure why I'm running into this issue. Everywhere I see where users are running into this issue it's because they forget to assign the `map` function to an array, however I have already done that.

**BONUS** If anybody can teach me how to use this method to create a `<Card>` object with multiple objects within it. I would really appreciate it. I'm not sure how I can reference multiple arrays with this method (I'm very new to expo and react-native).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render Content Dynamically from an array map function in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446029/render-content-dynamically-from-an-array-map-function-in-react-native)

Comment: @Wolverine I'm confused. The answer was to `return` the mapped array. However you can see I've already done that

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I entered the `state` objects into a `constructor(props)` method as such:

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            txt: ["Hello", "My", "Friend"],
            tuxt: ["Whats","up","Bussy"],
            key: [0,1,2]
        }
    }
```

this has solved my problem.